# Highlighting box for provisional data on Viz

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to create a box(shaded with a different color to the background) to show the fact that the last 3 days are provisional data. I want to do this on a line chart that has date on the x-axis and a value on the y-axis. If there is a filter on the dates displayed the box should only show up on the last three days relative to the current date(which is the last date in the date field).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about this use case in a recent blog post showing [how to shade a Tableau chart](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/how-to-shade-a-tableau-bar-chart/). The same solution should apply here. Create a calculated field based on the dates you want to mark as provisional. Something like:

```
[Date]>=DATEADD('day',-3,{MAX([Date])})
```

Use that and format the shading. The article has the full explanation with images - it's a bit long to post in this response.

Comment: That explanation is really good and does pretty close to what I want. I would like this to be in a line graph format and it interrupts the connection from inside to out of the period.